# Active Directory Trusts and Schema

Tags: windows, active-directory, schema

Our company is in the process of implementing a "cloud proxy" that will utilize Active Directory for user/password lookup.  The idea is to expend this and build trusts to customer's AD.

My Question is, do schema's need to be the same when implementing trusts?  For example customer A has a custom schema, would the schema cause problems if customer B has also a custom setup?

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no connection between schema and authentication.